# Adjusting distance of two decorative ornamentals at the top of the page

Tags: decorations, tikz-decorations, pgfornament

I'm trying to reproduce the preface page ornament design of the Westlake's *How to write letters* book. This is a capture of that page with the decoration:[image]

In doing so, I've used the *pgfornament package*, from which I selected a pair of ornaments so I can join them to reproduce that antique ornament. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \fbox{\parbox{95mm}{
            \begin{minipage}{50mm}
                \begin{minipage}{1mm}
                    \pgfornament[scale=0.5]{55}
                \end{minipage}%
            \hspace{45mm}
                \begin{minipage}{1mm}
                    \pgfornament[scale=0.5]{56}
                \end{minipage}
            \end{minipage}
    }}
    \end{center}\vspace{20pt}

\begin{center}
    {\LARGE\sc Some title}
\end{center}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image]

However, I do not know how to adjsut automatically the distance between the ornaments. Every time the scale or the ornament number is changed, the distance has to be adjusted manually changing the value of `\hspace{}`. Also, the `\parbox{}` size gives the same trouble when those features are changed.

Could anyone help me to fix that in order to get this things sorted out automatically or more efficiently?

---

**Note.** I think the package *tikz* would help, but I'm not sure how to use it. All I know about tikz is summarised in the next code:

```
\fbox{\parbox{98mm}{
    \begin{minipage}{50mm}
        \begin{minipage}{1mm}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[rotate=0] (a) {\pgfornament[scale=0.5]{55}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}\hspace*{\fill}%\hfill%\hspace{55mm}
        \begin{minipage}{1mm}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[rotate=0] (b) {\pgfornament[scale=0.5]{56}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}
    }}
```

The latter produces the former problems but quite similar results:

[image]

Comment: You can reproduce the box with `\fbox{\pgfornament[scale=0.5]{55}\!\!\pgfornament[scale=0.5]{56}}`, but I do not know if there is a simple way to know the negative space one has to insert. In principle the ornament codes have a code for `use as bounding box` (`\ubb`), but this only seems to get used in one of the actual ornaments.

Answer (score 1):

The `pgfornament` package has a `width` option, where one can define how much horizontal space a decoration will take.

Using that, and streamlining your example, I could produce a couple of pages looking something like this--

[image: Page-decor]

with something like this piece of code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \fbox{\parbox{95mm}{
              \hfil
            \pgfornament[width=45mm]{55}%
              %\hfil
            \pgfornament[width=45mm]{56} }}\\[20mm]
    %
         {\LARGE\scshape Some title}
    \end{center}
\lipsum[1-2]

\clearpage

    \begin{center}
    \fbox{\parbox{95mm}{
              \hfil
            \pgfornament[width=45mm]{46}%
              \hfil
            \pgfornament[width=45mm]{46} }}\\[20mm]
    %
         {\LARGE\scshape A new title}
    \end{center}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

where `\hfil` nicely arranges a pair of decorations (each of `width=45mm`) inside the `\parbox{95mm}`.

We may choose [not] to use the interim `\hfil` if we [do not] want a space between the two decorations.
The first page *does not*, while the second *does* use the intermediate `\hfil`.

### Edit

When compiling in Overleaf, I am getting a space in-between the two decorations (as the OP comments), even if the first one ended with a `%`.

The package option `inner sep=0pt` mentioned in p.12-13 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/pgfornament/doc/ornaments.pdf) used within a `tikz` `node` can be an option to rescue in this case.

Also note the `symmetry=v` option which adds the freedom to mirror any decoration without the necessity to have the specific pair in the library.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \fbox{\parbox{95mm}{
              \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \node[left,inner sep=0pt]  at (0,0)  
             {\pgfornament[width=40mm]{55}};%
          \node[right,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) 
             {\pgfornament[width=40mm,symmetry=v]{55}}; 
        \end{tikzpicture}
              \end{center}}}\\[20mm]
    %
         {\LARGE\scshape Some title}
    \end{center}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello,  Partha. I tried your solution but I didn't get the same result: the ornaments still separated from each other. I thought it was my  tex version  but copying the same first part code in overleaf the result was just the same :(   Any alternative?

Comment: My LaTeX version did not show the gap, but strangely Overleaf did.  It might have to do with the package version... not sure.  Anyway, edited the post to address the issue.